# How do IBMs lis and ori instructions work?

Tags: assembly, powerpc, instruction-set

I want to know how do `lis` and `ori` instructions work? There is a description [IBM description](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.aixassem/doc/alangref/ori.htm%23a1yp1a0ken) which i cannot understand well. Could someone explain to me what is the result on this example:

```
lis r1, 0x0028      
ori r1, r1, 0x776F
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lis` is defined here ( http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.aixassem/doc/alangref/fixed_point_load.htm#idx175 )

> Extended Mnemonic `lis rx, value` => Equivalent to `addis rx, 0, value`. aka Load Immediate Shifted

`addis` is then defined as:

> Calculates an address from a concatenated offset and a base address and loads the result in a general-purpose register.

The "Load Immediate Shifted" operation is described on this page ( http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-ppc/ ):

> Conveniently, lis (meaning "load immediate shifted") will load directly into the high 16 bits of the GPR. Then all that's left to do is add in the lower bits.

So `lis r1, 0x0028` is `addis r1, 0, 0x0028`, in English: Set the upper 16 bits of the contents of register `r1` to 0x0028.  (And zero the other bits, because we added `0x28 << 16` to `0`.)

I think `ori`'s definition is straight-forward:

> Logically ORs the lower 16 bits of the contents of a general-purpose register with a 16-bit unsigned integer and stores the result in another general-purpose register.

In your example, `ori r1, r1, 0x776F`:

In English: Get the lower 16-bits of whatever is in register `r1` and OR them with 0x776F ( `1110111 01101111` ) then store it back in `r1`.

---

So those two instructions form `0x0028776F` in register `r1`, with no dependency on the previous contents.

The low 16 bits are zero after `addis`, so ORing into them just sets them to `ori`'s immediate.

A 2-instruction sequence like this (special instruction to set high bits, then `addi` or `ori` to set the low bits) is typical of RISC ISAs for constructing arbitrary 32-bit constants; a 32-bit instruction word doesn't have room for a whole 32-bit immediate.

Comment: This doesn't depend on the original contents of r1; the because the second operand to `addis` is zero, we just set `r1` to `(value << 16) + 0`